# getSharedPreferences Lifetime

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

scenario :

User install the apk.
Then data stored in the `getSharedPreferences`
Then User unInstall the apk.
Whether the data in the `getSharedPreferences` are deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `SharedPreferences` will be deleted when the app is uninstalled.